# day of the week as X in Seaborn plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset with clicks and impressions, I aggregated them by the day of week using groupby and agg

```
df2=df.groupby('day_of_week',as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True).agg({'Clicks':'sum','Impressions':'sum'})
```

Then I was trying to plot them out using subplot

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 7))
sns.countplot(data=df2['Clicks'], x=df2['day_of_week'],ax=axes[0, 0])
sns.countplot(data=df2["Impressions"], x=df2['day_of_week'],ax=axes[0, 1])
```

but instead using the day of week as the X, the plot used values in clicks and impressions instead. Is there a way to force the X to day of the week while value is in Y instead? Thanks.

Full code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

df=pd.read_csv('data/data_clean.csv')

df2=df.groupby('day_of_week',as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True).agg({'Clicks':'sum','Impressions':'sum'})

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 7))
sns.countplot(data=df2['Clicks'], x=df2['day_of_week'],ax=axes[0, 0])
sns.countplot(data=df2["Impressions"], x=df2['day_of_week'],ax=axes[0, 1])

plt.show()
```

Fake Data:

```
day_of_week,Clicks,Impressions
 0           100       2000
 1           400       4000
 2           300       3500
 3           200       2000
 4           100       1000
 5           50        500
 6           10        150
```

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve], then [edit] your question to contain such a runnable example. Then clearly explain what you want to see instead.

Comment: Done, sorry for not being clear earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer with seaborn with Peter's guidance.

The correct plotting code is

```
sns.barplot( x=df2['day_of_week'],y=df2['Clicks'] , color="skyblue", ax=axes[0, 0])
sns.barplot( x=df2['day_of_week'],y=df2['Impressions'] , color="olive", ax=axes[0, 1])
```

It seems seaborn by default would take the first variable as X instead of Y.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the seaborn docs, I think `countplot` expects a long-form dataframe such as your `df`, *not* the pre-aggregated `df2` that you built and pass in your question. `countplot` does the counting for you.

However, your `df2` is ready for a pandas bar plot:

```
df2.plot(kind='bar', y=['Impressions', 'Clicks'])
```

Result:
[image: pandas bar plot of df2]

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into documentation now to create this in different subplots.